# how to split string/numbers from a string in python

Tags: python

I have the following string patterns:

```py
A = 'this is an_example-0--1.5-60-NA'
```

The separator is a hyphen but there are mixed positive/negative numbers. I want to extract the following strings:

```py
string[0] = 'this is an_example'
string[1] = -1.5
string[2] = 60
string[3] = 'NA'
```

`string[1]` and `string[2]` can be either positive or negative. `string.split('-')` doesn't work here.

Comment: There is a `0` in your example. Should it be omitted?

Comment: Seems like the correct solution is to use some other character as the separator.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/) to split by a `'-'` *not followed by another* `'-'`.

```
import re

A = 'this is an_example-0--1.5-60-NA'

splitted = re.split(r'(?<!-)-', A)

print(splitted)
#outputs
#['this is an_example', '0', '-1.5', '60', 'NA']
```